I want to create a datamapplot on my streamlit application but it keeps crashing
I have the following code that is running on a streamlit application...
      embeds_2d: pd.DataFrame = visualizer(topics)
            data = embeds_2d[["x", "y"]].values 
            labels = embeds_2d["labels"].values 

            with st.spinner("Rendering the image..."): 
                with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as tmp_dir: 
                    fig, ax = datamapplot.create_plot(
                        data, labels, 
                        noise_label="Unimportant topics", 
                        title="Topic Map", 
                        sub_title="Visual representation of topics found within the book", 
                        label_font_size=11, 
                    )

                    fig.savefig(f"{tmp_dir}/saved_img.jpg")
                    matplotlib_fig = PIL.Image.open(f"{tmp_dir}/saved_img.jpg") 
                    st.plotly_chart(matplotlib_fig)


I expected this to work but the application waits for the model so long that the application seems to crash every time this piece of code runs.
I thought there might be something wrong with the datamapplot class itself, so I tried running it locally.
It worked fine.
Then I thought, since it doesn't work on the streamlit application but works locally, perhaps I could add an endpoint to an existing server that I am making in fastapi and see if that gives me any results.
So I made the following endpoint in my existing server.
@app.post("/create_img")
async def create_image(img_model: DataMapPlotInputModel) -> GeneratedImageModel: 
    with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as tmp_dir: 
        data = np.hstack((np.array(img_model.X_col).reshape(-1, 1), 
                   np.array(img_model.Y_col).reshape(-1, 1)))  

        labels = np.array(img_model.labels).reshape(-1,)

        fig, _ = datamapplot.create_plot(
            data, labels, 
            noise_label="Unimportant topics", 
            title="Topic Map", 
            sub_title="Visual representation of topics found within the book", 
            label_font_size=11, 
        )

        fig.savefig(f"{tmp_dir}/saved_img.jpg")
        matplotlib_fig = PIL.Image.open(f"{tmp_dir}/saved_img.jpg") 


        return GeneratedImageModel(
            encoded_image=encode_image(matplotlib_fig)
        )

I ran the endpoint independent of the streamlit application as follows:
import numpy as np
import requests
import io
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from image_utils.decoder import decode_image
import matplotlib 

matplotlib.rcParams["figure.dpi"] = 72
URL: str = "http://127.0.0.1:8000"

data_map_file = requests.get("https://github.com/TutteInstitute/datamapplot/raw/main/examples/Wikipedia-data_map.npy")
wikipedia_data_map = np.load(io.BytesIO(data_map_file.content))
label_file = requests.get(
    "https://github.com/TutteInstitute/datamapplot/raw/main/examples/Wikipedia-cluster_labels.npy")

wikipedia_labels = np.load(io.BytesIO(label_file.content), allow_pickle=True)
x_col = wikipedia_data_map[:, 0].tolist()[0:10]
y_col = wikipedia_data_map[:, 1].tolist()[0:10]
labels = wikipedia_labels.tolist()[0:10]
response = requests.post(URL + "/create_img", json={
    "X_col":x_col, 
    "Y_col": y_col,
    "labels": labels, 
}, timeout=1000)

img = decode_image(response.json()["encoded_image"])
print(np.asarray(img)) 

This code worked some of the times but other times the Connection Got aborted, facing a similar issue. Mind you, this variation in behaviour was observed for the exact same input. So I'm confused. What is going on ? How do I resolve this issue?
